# Tensor Product Algorithm Optimization

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization

```
double data[12] = {1, z, z^2, z^3, 1, y, y^2, y^3, 1, x, x^2, x^3};
double result[64] = {1, z, z^2, z^3, y, zy, (z^2)y, (z^3)y, y^2, z(y^2), (z^2)(y^2), (z^3)(y^2), y^3, z(y^3), (z^2)(y^3), (z^3)(y^3), x, zx, (z^2)x, (z^3)x, yx, zyx, (z^2)yx, (z^3)yx, (y^2)x, z(y^2)x, (z^2)(y^2)x, (z^3)(y^2)x, (y^3)x, z(y^3)x, (z^2)(y^3)x, (z^3)(y^3)x, x^2, z(x^2), (z^2)(x^2), (z^3)(x^2), y(x^2), zy(x^2), (z^2)y(x^2), (z^3)y(x^2), (y^2)(x^2), z(y^2)(x^2), (z^2)(y^2)(x^2), (z^3)(y^2)(x^2), (y^3)(x^2), z(y^3)(x^2), (z^2)(y^3)(x^2), (z^3)(y^3)(x^2), x^3, z(x^3), (z^2)(x^3), (z^3)(x^3), y(x^3), zy(x^3), (z^2)y(x^3), (z^3)y(x^3), (y^2)(x^3), z(y^2)(x^3), (z^2)(y^2)(x^3), (z^3)(y^2)(x^3), (y^3)(x^3), z(y^3)(x^3), (z^2)(y^3)(x^3), (z^3)(y^3)(x^3)};
```

- What is the fastest (fewest executions) to produce **result** given **data**? Assume, that **data** is variable in size, but always a factor of 4 (e.g., 4, 8, 12, etc.).
- No Boost. I am trying to keep my dependencies small. STL Algorithms are ok.
- HINT: result array size should always be 4^(multiple size) (e.g., 4, 16, 64, etc.).
- BONUS: If you can compute **result** just given x, y, z

Additional examples:

```
double data[4] = {1, z, z^2, z^3};
double result[4] = {1, z, z^2, z^3};

double data[8] = {1, z, z^2, z^3, 1, y, y^2, y^3};
double result[16] = { ... };
```

**I chose the accepted answer code after running this benchmark: https://gist.github.com/1232406. Basically, the top two codes were run and the one with the smallest execution time won.**

Comment: Do you have an algorithm that's too slow, or do you need an algorithm?

Comment: @Als Not homework; its for work.

Comment: @Seth I do already have a solution but it is slow, and introduces outside dependencies (specifically Eigen http://eigen.tuxfamily.org) to perform the Kronecker product.

Comment: If you're using Eigen, and it's slow, then either you're doing it wrong or doing it faster would mean Intel Math Library magic.

Comment: I very well could be doing it wrong using Eigen; I will grant that. Basically, I cannot get Eigen to perform the Kronecker product on a `Map<VectorXd>` without creating a copy of the `Map` thus performing a memory allocation and then copy, thus slowing down the execution.

Comment: What is `Map<VectorXd>`? `std::map` takes two template args. Post some relevant code in the question perhaps?

Comment: @Ryan - Maybe if you post some of your code, someone might be able to help you spot the slow parts. But right now there's not enough info to be much help.

Comment: Eigen source code included now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>A good compiler will autovectorize this</strike> I guess none of my compilers are good:

```
void tensor(const double *restrict data,
            int dimensions,
            double *restrict result) {
  result[0] = 1.0;
  for (int i = 0; i < dimensions; i++) {
    for (int j = (1 << (i * 2)) - 1; j > -1; j--) {
      double alpha = result[j];
      {
        double *restrict dst = &result[j * 4];
        const double *restrict src = &data[(dimensions - 1 - i) * 4];
        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) dst[k] = alpha * src[k];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This works somewhat. I'm using VS 2010 and the `restrict` keyword is not valid; it uses `__restrict`. Also, for some reason when the code is run after using the compiler optimization it does not work; though if I run it with no optimization it does work.

Comment: Removing the `__restrict` keyword in VS fixes the compiler optimization errors.

Comment: @Ryan: Obviously, time several of these answers.  This one writes some elements of the array several times, but the code is so _small_ that it may perform better in the caches, so it may be faster than other methods.

Comment: @Mooing Duck _This one writes some elements of the array several times_ This one doesn't assume that the first element of each quad is 1. It would be easy enough to avoid the extraneous writes under that assumption.

Comment: @the guy formerly known as d: I don't know that that's the issue at hand.  I'm referring to the last iteration of the biggest loop, when `i==dimensions-1`, it will write the entire first quarter of the array even though it's all already assigned.  Although... it should be possible to change the `j > -1` to something else and make this the fastest answer by far.

Comment: @the guy formerly known as d: Actually, yes.  You are right.  I got it now.  However, it can be faster given that the first element of each quad is 1.  http://ideone.com/wRCaw

Comment: I accepted this answer. Though technically it was Mooning Ducks answer (http://ideone.com/wRCaw) that proved to be the fastest. If you move that to its own answer I'll accept that one. Here is the benchmark I ran: https://gist.github.com/1232406

Comment: @Ryan: It's just a simpilified version of QWERTY's answer, so he deserves the credit.

Comment: @Ryan: I modified the test to output the first and last ten numbers of the array to validate results, and only the fast one seems to be working :(

Answer (score 2):

```
void Tensor(std::vector<double>& result, double x, double y, double z) {
    result.resize(64); //almost noop if already right size
    double tz = z*z;
    double ty = y*y;
    double tx = x*x;
    std::array<double, 12> data = {0, 0, tz, tz*z, 1, y, ty, ty*y, 1, x, tx, tx*x};
    register std::vector<double>::iterator iter = result.begin();
    register int yi;
    register double xy;
    for(register int xi=0; xi<4; ++xi) {
        for(yi=0; yi<4; ++yi) {
            xy = data[4+yi]*data[8+xi];
            *iter = xy; //a smart compiler can do these four in parallell
            *(++iter) = z*xy;
            *(++iter) = data[2]*xy;
            *(++iter) = data[3]*xy;
            ++iter; //workaround for speed!
        }
    }        
}
```

There's probably at least one bug in here somewhere, but it should be fast, with no dependancies (outside of `std::vector`/`std::array`), just takes x,y,z.  I avoided recursion though, so it only works for 3 in/64 out.  The concept can be applied to any number of parameters though.  You just have to instantiate yourself.

Comment: Use `register int xi, yi; register double xy;` before the loops and `xy = data[4+yi]*data[8+xi]; *iter = xy; *(++iter) = z*xy; *(++iter) = data[2]*xy; *(++iter) = data[3]*xy; ++iter;` in loop body. `iter++` usually implemented as `iterator temp(*this); ++(*this); return temp;`.

Comment: I usually ignore the `register` keyword because my compiler does.  I added it in case some compiler still cares about it.  I know about the `++iter` vs `iter++`, but since it's in a loop, that optimization doesn't work here.  Also, since `vector::iterator` is basically a pointer, it's not really a slowdown.

Comment: Did not fully understand the question nor properly read the answer, but +1 for the effort!

Comment: I have run the code and it properly does the example case that I showed above. So I up voted the answer. The reason I haven't accepted it is it does not yet work for the generic case. I'm working on it right now and when I get your method expanded I'll accept the answer.

Comment: which generic case?  More variables? Different types of variables?  powers of 0-N?

Comment: More or less variables. What if there is only `x` and `y`? Or what if there is `x`, `y`, `z`, `w`, `...`?

Comment: Use `register int yi; register double xy;` before the loops. In your way `int` and `double` is created in memory and deleted in every loops. If you create them before the loops, just the values will be changed. Unfortunatelly not all of the compilers optimize that case. Cheers :)

Comment: any compiler worth it's salt will handle that automatically, but W/E.  Also @Ryan: added another answer that takes any number of parameters.

Answer (score 1):

you should use dynamic algorithm. that is, you can use previous results. for example, you keep y^2 result and use it when computing (y^2)z instead of computing it again.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <vector> 
#include <cstddef>
#include <cmath>

void Tensor(std::vector<double>& result, const std::vector<double>& variables, size_t index)    
{
    double p1 = variables[index];
    double p2 = p1*p1;
    double p3 = p1*p2;
    if (index == variables.size() - 1) {
        result.push_back(1);
        result.push_back(p1);
        result.push_back(p2);
        result.push_back(p3);
    } else {
        Tensor(result, variables, index+1);
        ptrdiff_t size = result.size();
        for(int j=0; j<size; ++j)
            result.push_back(result[j]*p1);
        for(int j=0; j<size; ++j)
            result.push_back(result[j]*p2);
        for(int j=0; j<size; ++j)
            result.push_back(result[j]*p3);
    }
}

std::vector<double> Tensor(const std::vector<double>& params) {
    std::vector<double> result;
    double rsize = (1<<(2*params.size());
    result.reserve(rsize);
    Tensor(result, params);
    return result;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<double> params;
    params.push_back(3.1415926535);
    params.push_back(2.7182818284);
    params.push_back(42);
    params.push_back(65536);
    std::vector<double> result = Tensor(params);
}
```

I verified that this one compiles and runs (http://ideone.com/IU1eQ).  It runs fast, with no dependancies (outside of std::vector). It also takes any number of parameters.  Since calling the recursive form is awkward, I made a wrapper.  It makes one function call for each parameter, and one call to dynamic memory (in the wrapper).

Answer (score 0):

You should look for [Pascal's pyramid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_pyramid) to get fast solution. [Useful link 1](https://www.mathsisfun.com/pascals-triangle.html), [useful link 2](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PascalsTriangle.html), [useful link 3](https://web.archive.org/web/20171223001308/http://mathforum.org/workshops/usi/pascal/pascal_binomial.html) and [useful link 4](https://web.archive.org/web/20160410142410/http://buckydome.com:80/math/Article2.htm).

One more thing: as I see it would be a base of a finite element solver. Usually to write own BLAS solver is not a good idea. Do not reinvent the wheel! I think you should use a BLAS solver like [intel MKL](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/oneapi/onemkl.html) or [Cuda base BLAS](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/).